# What is the probability of something happening when the odds have been surpassed?

Tags: statistics

Let’s say the chances of an event happening is 1/500. Each try is independent, and does not affect any subsequent tries. I know by the binomial distribution that once you’ve “rolled” 500 times, there is about a 63% chance it’ll have happened at least once. My question is, what is the exact probability of it happening on the 501st try, or the 502nd, and every consecutive one after that?

Comment: Please clarify which probability you want to calculate? P(not 500 times but on the 501st try) or P(501st try | not 500 times) or what?

Comment: As the events are independent, and you assume that the first 500 tries already had happened, the single probability that it happens on the 501st try is simply 1/500. That's also why it doesn't make sense to say "It didn't happen so far, so it need to happen now" - No, for each single experiment the probability is 1/500

Comment: Fair enough. I don’t know why I assumed the probability of it happening would “increase” in a sense because the probability of it having happened increases as you go up. I thought there could be some sort of interpolation

Comment: The same applies if the (unlikely) event happened twice in a row. This does not mean that it cannot happen a third time in a row. The probability does not change.

Comment: If you look at the overall event occurrences you can say that it's less likely that it happens twice in a row. But looking at each new event individually, you cannot say anything about the outcome if you know the previous results.